# How to access an object methods if he is nested in another object instance?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I use a library called [AnimOnScroll](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/) that I instantiate on my page load like that:

```
    new AnimOnScroll( this.find('#grid' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
    } );
```

As shown in the code, the AnimOnScroll object instance is attached to a `div`with  `#grid` id.

In the AnimOnScroll javascript file, another library ([masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)) is called in the constructor like that (I removed the option part to make it simple to read here):

```
function AnimOnScroll( el, options ) {  
    this.el = el;
    this._init();
}
AnimOnScroll.prototype = {

    _init : function() {


        var self = this;

        imagesLoaded( this.el, function() {

            // initialize masonry
            new Masonry( self.el, {
                itemSelector: 'li',
                transitionDuration : 0
            } );
```

I want to access masonry methods but I can't find how to reach its object instance within AnimOnScroll.

I managed to reload the items by recreating a new instance of AnimOnScroll everytime but I want to learn how to do it cleanly in this case (still new to javascript).

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I gave it another try to test @Nick L. answer. It turns out that if I use `self.prototype.masonry = new Masonry( ...` I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'masonry' of undefined`

If I replace this line with `self.masonry = new Masonry( ...` it works fine. I can get the AnimOnLoad object showing on the console with masonry exposed[image]

Following how you named your variables, I get that by logging `scroll`. if I try to log `masonry` (i.e. `scroll.masonry`) it appears as `undefined`.

Any idea?

**EDIT 2**

When looking at the callback logs in the instantiation of AnimOnScroll, I realized the object is created after my page is rendered. That was my first mistake, trying to call it when it wasn't loaded.

My second mistake was to assume that I could use masonry methods without display issue. This object (AnimOnScoll) attach a "shown" class to each object to handle the transitions and keep track of the scrolling position.

I would have to rewrite a method for each masonry method I need to use. Bottom line: I will choose the path of less resistance, re-creating the AnimOnScroll object instance every time I need a refresh. that's working fine. For those interested, I use the helper that provide the displayed items collection. Just before it returns it, I added:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
    if(typeof scroller!=undefined){scroller= new AnimOnScroll(.......)}
                  },100);
```

That way, AnimOnScroll reloads right after my page is updated and it works smoothly.

And I'll validate your answer, @Nick L. because it was nice of you to help me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access an object methods, you need to have somehow access to the object itself, in general terms.

I suggest you add a masonry property containing the `Masonry` instance on the object using `self`, then pass the constructed object there:

```
//Warning: Untested code


AnimOnScroll.prototype = {

    _init : function() {

        var self = this;

        imagesLoaded( this.el, function() {

        // initialize masonry
        self.masonry = new Masonry( self.el, {
            itemSelector: 'li',
            transitionDuration : 0
        } );
    }
}
```

Then, access the `Masonry` object by doing:

```
var scroll  = new AnimOnScroll();
var masonry = scroll.masonry;
//etc
```

EDIT: Consider checking step-by-step several times using a debugger or  `console.log` whether or not the object is invoked, starting from where you call its constructor up to where it is called and not found, in order to ensure its correct construction and usage.

Comment: I did the exact same thing than what you suggest, except I added a _reload function calling this.masonry in animeOnScroll. It didn't work, but I did not insist. I am gonna try again with your approach. Thanks for answering!

Comment: When try with your line `self.prototype.masonry = new Masonry( ...` I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'masonry' of undefined`.

Comment: The code is untested, the point is that you pass the object to a property var of the object. Planning to test it ASAP.

Comment: This is really strange: I can access/log all the other properties (e.g. `scroll.items`) but not `scroll.masonry`. Could it be because it is another object? I don't get what I miss. Take a look at my screen capture: why does `masonry`attribute display a value `n` instead of `Object`?

Comment: Are you sure the callback has been invoked, in order to add the property?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. I started to work with javascript one month ago so I could miss something obvious. No other property of animOnScroll is defined with more than `this.item = something` and they all work. I tried to make a function like `function masonry (){return this.masonry}` but it didn't change the problem.

Comment: Add an alert or a console.log command inside `imagesLoaded` callback and check if it is invoked.

Comment: The `console.log` inside `imagesLoaded` callback show it is invoked when I call `self.masonry`. However, it is logged as "n" where I would expect the name of the property. Should we move on chat?

Comment: Kinda. Look at the second edit in my question. I think it would require more work to handle the display for each masonry method relatively to the viewport/AnimOnScroll approach.

Comment: OK, If you consider that my answer did not cover you, please answer your question with what you found and choose it as best. It is not about rep, afterall. :)

Comment: No need for another answer, you covered my question (accessing a nested object). Maybe you can just add a line of warning "Check several times using `console.log` if the object is invoked, starting from where you call its constructor up to where it is called and not found. It allows you to make sure that the object is instantiated *before* you invoke it"

Comment: Added it slightly modified. Thanks!